# Can't make migrations of my django deployment app

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

My app is deployed with gunicorn+nginx and it worked fine before I started to make migrations today.
Now the app is running (by the way, I don't know why it's working) but i can't go to the Admin page, I get an error after login (I made DEBUG=True to understand what's happening):

`ProgrammingError at /admin/login/
relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user...`

What I did before this:
After a couple of failed migration attempts, I dropped my database and created it again with the same name. Then

```
rm -rf <app>/migrations/
```

Then I try:

```
python3 manage.py migrate --fake
```

get this:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying auth.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying admin.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... FAKED
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... FAKED
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... FAKED
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... FAKED
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... FAKED
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... FAKED
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... FAKED
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... FAKED
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... FAKED
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... FAKED
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... FAKED
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... FAKED
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... FAKED
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... FAKED


python3 manage.py makemigrations myapp

Migrations for 'myapp':
  myapp/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model table1
    - Create model table2
    - Create model table3
    - Create model table4


 python3 manage.py migrate --fake-initial
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, myapp, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying myapp.0001_initial... FAKED
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "django_content_type" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "django_co...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 257, in handle
    self.verbosity, self.interactive, connection.alias, apps=post_migrate_apps, plan=plan,
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 51, in emit_post_migrate_signal
    **kwargs
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 175, in send
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 175, in <listcomp>
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 42, in create_permissions
    create_contenttypes(app_config, verbosity=verbosity, interactive=interactive, using=using, apps=apps, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/management/__init__.py", line 118, in create_contenttypes
    content_types, app_models = get_contenttypes_and_models(app_config, using, ContentType)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/management/__init__.py", line 95, in get_contenttypes_and_models
    for ct in ContentType.objects.using(using).filter(app_label=app_config.label)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 274, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 55, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1097, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "django_co...
                                                             ^

python3 manage.py migrate auth
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: auth
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "django_content_type" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "django_co...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 257, in handle
    self.verbosity, self.interactive, connection.alias, apps=post_migrate_apps, plan=plan,
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 51, in emit_post_migrate_signal
    **kwargs
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 175, in send
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 175, in <listcomp>
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 42, in create_permissions
    create_contenttypes(app_config, verbosity=verbosity, interactive=interactive, using=using, apps=apps, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/management/__init__.py", line 118, in create_contenttypes
    content_types, app_models = get_contenttypes_and_models(app_config, using, ContentType)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/management/__init__.py", line 95, in get_contenttypes_and_models
    for ct in ContentType.objects.using(using).filter(app_label=app_config.label)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 274, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 55, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1097, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "django_co...
```

I tried everything I could find in google... Have no idea what to do

Edit: and if i do just makemigrations -> migrate i get the same error

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "django_co...
```

And in my local server everything works ok with all changes I've done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by downgrading Django to 2.2 and dropping my database.

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
blank=True
```

in the new added field